# Access intellij environment variable in external tools

Tags: intellij-idea

As part of run configurations of my application in Intellij, i need to run a shell script. But this script expects a param which depends on environment variable. `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=platform-2-dev`

I am doing this by adding external tool in before launch tasks(after build task execution).

[image]

However, at runtime, Intellij does n't seem to access the variable by specifying as [image]

$SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE, however, it seems to work correctly on specifying platform-2-dev. Can anyone please help?

Comment: There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-14429/It-isnt-possible-to-specify-environment-variables-for-external-tools